# Vignette in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

So this is what I have for a vignette style effect in Android (image is a Bitmap):

```
public void vignette() {
    float radius = (float) (image.getWidth()/1.5);
    RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, radius, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawARGB(1, 0, 0, 0);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setShader(gradient);

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    final RectF rectf = new RectF(rect);

    canvas.drawRect(rectf, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, rect, rect, paint);
}
```

This "works" but there are a couple of problems. First of all, this is not really a vignette, it's just a gradient so you can see bits of the black going nearly all the way to the center rather than feathering out closer to the edges.

The RadialGradient used also only allows for setting the radius of a circle rather than an ellipse. An ellipse would be able to more effectively match the dimensions of a non-square image than a circle.

The quality of the gradient is also not superb.

I'm trying to replicate the vignetteImage method from ImageMagick (I'm referring specifically to the php version). I have this code in PHP that produces the style of image that I want:

```
$im = new IMagick('city.png');
$im->vignetteImage($width/1.5, 350, 20, 20);
```

I've tried building ImageMagick with the NDK but have been unsuccessful in properly linking the various image libraries (I've only successfully built with gif support but no png, jpeg or tiff).

I've also attached an image comparing the two methods shown above. The image on the left was generated with ImageMagick through php and the image on the right was generated using the method shown above for Android.

[image: left: vignette from php/ImageMagick. right: vignette from Android using method shown above]

Comment: You got any solution for that....If yes than you can provide it to me.....?.......Thank you

Comment: So far geeknizer's answer is the best I have. I haven't tried it out yet though .... getting to that this morning.

Comment: A bit late but, Did you got any solution for this problem? Is so, could you provide the code? You would save my life if so! @greggory.hz

Comment: I was never able to match ImageMagick exactly. I did end up playing more with building ImageMagick for android with mixed results. Eventually, we moved on to other projects since this wasn't a vital component. However, as of API 14 (ICS) it has built in support for this effect: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html#EFFECT_VIGNETTE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look carefully at the image on left, tf uses exponential increase in Alpha (transparency) vs. image on right which is very linear.

Clearly `Shader.TitleMode.CLAMP` is a linear function. What you should do instead is use [RadialGradient(float x, float y, float radius, int[] colors, float[] positions, Shader.TileMode tile)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html#RadialGradient%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29) to define 10 or more points on the image with exponentially decreasing color values (black to transparent).

Alternatively, you can refer gallery 3d source for ICS gallery http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/gallery3d/photoeditor/filters/VignetteFilter.java?av=h

Comment: This seems to be the way to go to get ride of the linear-ness of the gradient. I'm probably going to have to play with the colors array to get it just right though. How does the positions array effect the whole thing? I'm not sure I totally understand that one. Now if I could figure out how to make it an ellipse ....

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old discussion but it may help someone.
You can use [AccelerateInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html#getInterpolation%28float%29) to generate the points that Taranfx had mentioned and it will lock awesome.